# hover won't work inside my navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create formatted links inside a navigation element on my website that turn black background-white text from the default background-black text when you hover over them. There are links enclosed in a nav element that don't but also the other links on the page don't work for hover as well.
I have attached the relevant css and html code to show the problem.

I have tried viewing the webpage in internet explorer edge and firefox

```
    <header>
        <img class="leftpane"; src="images/emailus.jpg" alt="email us Title">
        <nav id="rightpane">
      <a href="about_page.html">About Me</a>
      <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>  
      <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>
      <a href="store.html">Store</a>
      <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a> 


        </nav>
        </header>
```

```
    a:link{
        color:black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    }
    a: visited {
    background-color: grey;
    color:black;
    }
    a: hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    }
    a:active{
    background-color:cyan;
    color:black;
    }

    /*the following styles the header image and navigation on all pages*/
    img#leftpane{
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    } 

    nav#rightpane {
    float:right;
    width:40%;
    font: bold 13px Verdana;
    display: inline;
    color: black;

    }
```

I expected a navigation menu of links that highlight as you hover along them. and turn cyan when you click them. but only the cyan part works and the hover does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the extra spaces between your element and hover/visited. 
Change `a: hover` to `a:hover`. Makes a difference.

```css
a:link{
    color:black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
a:visited {
background-color: grey;
color:black;
}
a:hover{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
a:active{
background-color:cyan;
color:black;
}

/*the following styles the header image and navigation on all pages*/
img#leftpane{
text-align: left;
float:left;
width:50%;
} 

nav#rightpane {
float:right;
width:40%;
font: bold 13px Verdana;
display: inline;
color: black;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="leftpane"; src="images/emailus.jpg" alt="email us Title">
  <nav id="rightpane">
    <a href="about_page.html">About Me</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>  
    <a href="resources.html">Resources</a>
    <a href="store.html">Store</a>
    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a> 


  </nav>
</header>
```